# .htaccess Redirect / Change URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, shopping-cart

I am having a trouble figuring out how to successfully use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite my urls for me.

Basically google has indexed my webstore, and now i have rebuilt it at a seperate location and none of the google links work.  Rather then go through google and set customURLs for my whole site i want to add some .htaccess code to redirect to my new store instead, but it needs to maintain the whole link, this is where im lost.

My old store was at

```
http://mystore.com/store/
```

My new store is at

```
http://mystore.com/shop/
```

So when users go to

```
http://mystore.com/store/categories/cheese/Mouldy/?page=5&sort=featured
```

I need them to be reirected to

```
http://mystore.com/shop/categories/cheese/Mouldy/?page=5&sort=featured
```

However, I need an exception to this rule to be my admin area.  So if i access:

```
http://mystore.com/store/admin/
```

I **DO NOT** want to end up at

```
http://mystore.com/shop/admin/
```

Because i still need accesss to my old admin panel.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this does what you're after.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^store/admin(/|$)
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ ^shop/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Let me know if it works for you :-)

Edit:

Hopefully this'll work.

```
RewriteRule ^store/admin(.*)$ ^store/admin$1
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ ^shop/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hey mate, This isnt workign for me, My .htaccess looks like this, is this correct:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
 RewriteEngine On  
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^store/admin  
        RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ ^shop/$1 [L,R=301]  
</IfModule>`

Comment: I've updated my answer, if that does not work, attempt to put a / in front of store/admin on the RewriteCond line

Comment: Just to check, where is the .htaccess stored? Above the store/shop I assume?

Comment: It is stored above /store/ - And ofcourse theres a seperate one in /shop/.

I also tried adding this to my root dir but did nothing

Comment: And to check, it's working except for the part of excluding that directory?